# How to push dynamic objects into angular formly?

Tags: angular, lodash, angular-formly

So I'm getting a bunch of values with lodash _get and now for each value I want to create a field, or push a new object into the fields array. Here is the values I'm getting which is fine.

```
      this.myService
    .findRoles(this.serviceId, this.userId)
    .subscribe((roles: any) => { 
      _.get(roles,'assigned')) // I get all values so ["retailManager", 
      "storeManager", "generalManager"]
    })
```

Now here is my angular formly field:

```
   public config = {
      showCancel: true,
       fields: [{
         key: ' ',
        type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
         label: 'Assigned Roles',
       },
  }, ]
}
```

I want each role I received to create a new field object and be put into that key value for each.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this - one way would be to  - inside the subscribe -
iterate the roles and build the object and push to the fields array.

```
.subscribe((roles: any) => { 
      _.get(roles,'assigned'));
      // pseudocode - for each role
      // fields.push({
              key: role, type" 'input' ...
            })
    })
```

hope this helps.